# Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: extjs, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

Loading a list from remote server using the following store

```js
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'MyAppName.view.home.OrderListViewModel',
    groupField: 'customer',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'ordersList.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'orders',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: {
        params: {},
        callback: function (records, options, success) {
            if (success) {
                alert('here I am');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It loaded the list properly, but looking at Chrome console appears de the error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').
```

Nad looking at firebug is like is still trying to load the list.

```
GET fabricList.php?_dc=1579631906478&page=1&start=0&limit=25
Params Headers Response
```

And the same is  happening with every `store:Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{})` that I'm uisng in the program.
I'm using the ExtJS version 7.0.0.40
I'll appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably this error indicates an incorrect data format with returned from your endpoint `fabricList.php`[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType). Please post data returned from `fabricList.php` and check here `Content-Type` header in response